# force user to input 0 or 1

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, input

I am trying to create m*n matrix, for this matrix I want the user to input either o or 1 only. I want to force the user until the user inputs either 0 or 1.

```
int m=2; int n=2; 
double[,] DOFmatrix = new double[m, n];
for (int i = 0; i <m; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    double input;
                    Console.Write("Enter value for node in (X,Y) direction either 0 or 1", i,j);
                    while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input)
                    {
                    Console.Write("Enter correct value for ({0},{1}): ", i, j);
                    }             
                    DOFmatrix[i, j] = input
                }
```

Comment: You better prepare some manacles to chain them to their computer.

Comment: try do while instead of while

Answer (score 0):

Here is it:

```
        namespace ConsoleApplication1
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    //matrix size is defined and matrix is created
                    int m = 3, n = 3;
                    int value = 0;
                    string input;
                    int[,] matrix = new int[m,n];
                    //instructions are given to the user
                    Console.WriteLine("Please fill the matrix whit values 0 or 1");
                    //matrix size is obtained and used to nest for to fill the matrix
                    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                        {
                            //do-while statement is used to *trap* the user
                            //until correct input is given
                            do
                            {
                                input = Console.ReadLine();
                                value = Convert.ToInt32(input);
                                if (value != 0 && value != 1)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Please write 0 or 1");
                                }
                            } while (value != 0 && value != 1);
                            matrix[i, j] = value;
                        }
                    }
                    //Matrix is printed to confirm the input is correct
                    Console.WriteLine("The resulting matrix is:");
                    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
                        {
                            Console.Write(matrix[i,j].ToString()+"\t");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
```

if you have any questions, let me know in the comments.